# good odb 2 bluetooth emulator for app development

Tags: bluetooth, emulation, simulator

I am developing an iOS and an Android app to communicate with a ODB II Bluetooth device. What would be a good software emulator of the ODB2 device?

I want to prevent programming for weeks in my car....